# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest XML data

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I have a major API request I´m trying to do with Powershell to send further on as JSON to PowerBI.
The XML format is as followed (but much larger):

```
<queryResponse last="99" first="0" count="2" type="APD" responseType="list" requestUrl="an URL" rootUrl="root URL">
   <entity dtoType="aPDDTO" type="APD" url="URL_ID">
      <accessPointDetailsDTO displayName="ID" id="ID">
         <adminStatus>ENABLE</adminStatus>
         <apType>AP2600I</apType>
         <clientCount_5GHz>2</clientCount_5GHz>
         <status>CLEARED</status>
         <type>UnifiedAp</type>
            <cdpNeighbors>
               <cdpNeighbor>
                  <capabilities>Switch IGMP </capabilities>
                  <duplex>Full Duplex</duplex>
                  <interfaceSpeed>100Mbps</interfaceSpeed>
```

I would like to be able to send not all but specified fields furter on.
I have a loop used before when a API used JSON which I tried to use:

```
while ($true) {
$AccessPointDetails = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $BasicCreds"}
    foreach ($AccessPoint in $AccessPointDetails) {
        $payload = @{
            "adminStatus" = $AccessPoint.adminStatus
      }
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
        sleep 100
    }
}
```

I don´t get any values so I guess It doesn´t know where the data is.

***EDIT 1***

I found some hint about doing like below to present the data at the end of my code:

```
[ xml ]$fileContents = Get-Content -Path $Result
```

The problem is it seems to dislike my first row in the data I'm trying to read from since it cast this error to me:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 0):

I Usually get the json content, write it into a simple txt file, add the rows or values i need and then convert it into Json.

This usually let me to avoid any kind of issue

Comment: I don´t want any files created. This data will be sent to PowerBI cloud service maybe 4 times per hour.

Comment: I want to fetch more then just adminstatus when the code works, but adminstatus is plain text (as seen above)